# How do I get the console to output in Chrome 60+ V8 debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, v8

For instance:

[image: Chrome 60]

When I press enter (after typing `childLogger` at the bottom) nothing happens. There's no output. There's no output in my terminal either. I'm used to being able to use the console to see my objects but it seems like since about Chrome 55 this just doesn't work.

I don't have any filters turned on.  I've tried selecting All in the filters. I've tried selecting just one or two in the filters. I've looked at all my terminals to see if the output is going there instead. However I can get output to my terminal if I use **console.dir**. But I don't want to do that, I want the normal object inspector that comes with Chrome (you know, expandable object properties etc).

I've seen other questions on here but they weren't current and the solutions didn't help.

Comment: Does this happen all the time, or just with logger objects?

Comment: everything, it doesn't matter

Comment: So if you just open the console and type `1+2` it doesn't print `3`? I haven't had any similar problems. Try disabling extensions to see if something is interfering.

Comment: @Barmar `--inspect` uses the Chrome v8 debugger. Note that the labels are `v8` and `debugging`. If I type `var a = 1 + 2;` in the console and then press enter while using the debugger there is no output and the command is not stored in console history.

Comment: I was confused because you also have the `google-chrome` tag and you mentioned Chrome v55. But now I see you're not actually using Chrome itself, you're using Chrome's debugger in Node.js.

Comment: So it seems like there's a problem with the way the debugger is integrated into the Node.js environment, because it works fine in Chrome itself.

Comment: It's certainly not a problem with your code, so I'm not sure what can be solved here. You should probably submit a Chrome bug report.